# how to manage APP constant value with database

Tags: django

I want to save constant values to database. And whenever I need the value, I should get the value from database. So, I making model like this.

```
class APP_Constant(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_name = 'MW_Constant'
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('I','Integer'),('S','String')))
    i_value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    s_value = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

def get_value(self,name):
    v = self.objects.filter(self.name=name)
    if v.type == 'I':
        return v.i_value
    else:
        return v.s_value

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I did not build yet. I want to know does it possible?
Please give any advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
@property
def value(self):
    return self.i_value if self.type == 'I' else self.s_value
```

Now, just need use app_constant_obj.value

Comment: I got "AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'value'"

Comment: Because you are trying to use .value from a list, and only objects have the property value.

Comment: filter() returns a queryset, not a object.

Comment: I call like this APP_Constant.objects.filter(name='DEFAULT_COUNT'). tell me how to use.

Comment: APP_Constant.objects.get(name='STORY_DEFAULT_COUNT').value

Comment: use APP_Constant.objects.get(name='STORY_DEFAULT_COUNT').value , it worked?